# how to disable video-js' control bar temporary with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, video

How can I disable or hide control bar of video-js player with a button?

I can realize it in HTML5 default player but cannot do it with video-js player.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it works for 4.4 and I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work on 4.5.

```
function buttonCall() {
    _V_.ControlBar.prototype.options.components = {

    }
}
```

Just call the function using your button (onClick="removeControl"). It removes all control bar for video.js.